# Random number between 0-250, but with help of a external number? Not so much PHP, more Math philosophy?

Tags: php, math, random

Ok, don't ask me why I need to do this, but I need to. Haha! It's probably not so much a php question, but I've no idea what it is then? A Math Problem? It becomes a more of a PHP question when the theory how I'm gonna do this is solved, and then I need probably need help with the code, if it isnt just plain simple!

I'm gonna try to explain this as good as I can! 
I want a random number between `0-250`. This random number between `0-250` must be generated only with the help of a random number betwenn `0-5000`.

So.

```
RandomNumber1 = 1-250.
```

`RandomNumber1` have to be generated only with the help of `RandomNumber2`.

```
RandomNumber2 = 1-5000.
```

I've no idea if this is understandable for anyone else but me, but this is how I **HAVE** to do it.

**Can** only be numbers like 1,4,24,124 etc. Not 1.4, 2,5 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `RandomNumber2` and divide it by 20, this will reduce the possible range down to that of `RandomNumber1`.

In other words, when we take `RN2` and divide it by `20`, we obtain a number that is equally likely to be anything in the range `[RN2_min / 20, RN2_max / 20)` - in this case that would be `[0 / 20, 5000 / 20]` which is `[0, 250]`, as desired.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesnt give me a random number? Just go with the problem that randomnumber1 has to be generated with a number between 1-5000. It's to complicated to explain why i need to do it, and it's probably a messy solution anyway!

Comment: `RandomNumber2` is random, therefore `RandomNumber2 / 20` is also random.

Answer (score 0):

```
$RandomNumber2 = rand()%5000;
srand($RandomNumber2);
$RandomNumber1 = rand()%250;
```

Comment: I don't think PHP guarantees perpetual repeatability of random sequences, so in a few versions the result could change. I.e. this is essentially the same as ignoring RandomNumber2 completely.